# Plotting maps in the sp package in R (changing the ratio aspect of a map)

Tags: r, plot

I have the following problem when displaying a spatial object:

```
Reproducible example:

x<-c(1:2000)
y<-c(rep(1:20, each=100))
xy <- cbind(x,y)
S <- SpatialPoints(xy)
plot(S)
```

Which gives the undesired left plot on the panel below. : 
[image]

However, I would like to reduce the bounding box limits on the y-axis, to show more detail on the y-axis, to achieve a plot similar to the plot on the right panel, but with an `sp` object. I thought it could be achieved with `ylim` and `xlim`. But that doesn't work. I also tried the following based on an example from the `sp` documentation.

```
 pin<-par("pin")
 dxy<-apply(bbox(S), 1, diff)
 ratio<-dxy[0]/dxy[2]
 par(pin=c(ratio*pin[0.1], pin[1]), xaxs="i", yaxs="i")
 plot(S, pch=0.1)
```

But I don't understand what lines 3 and 4 do and I did try to play around with the values to no avail. Can anyone provide any suggestions please? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just discovered that `asp` works, so `plot(S, asp = 0)` solves the problem.